# Problem with bounding box in model space and intersection with ray

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, bounding-boxes

I have a bounding box in model space and I want to intersect it with a ray. I have tried to transform the ray like [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/79838/483278.aspx). Rotating and scaling works well, but transition does not.

Here is my code:

```
Xbouding = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(50, 10, 10), new Vector3(120, -10, -10));

ray.Position = Vector3.Transform(ray.Position, Matrix.Invert(MathUtil.CreateWorldMatrix(Position, Rotation, Scale)));
ray.Direction= Vector3.Transform(ray.Direction, Matrix.Invert(MathUtil.CreateWorldMatrix(Position, Rotation, Scale)));
float? dist = ray.Intersects(Xbouding);
```

I have this: 
[image: this is what I have]

I want to know if the ray from the mouse intersects with the boxes shown in the image. Pick works fine unless the model is translated (rotating and scaling works).

Another little question: what does `float?` mean? What's the difference between `float` and `float?`?

Comment: Position- and direction-vectors must be transformed differently. `ray.Direction` must be transformed using `Vector3.TransformNormal`, the position however must be transformed with `Vector3.Transform` as you already did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translation should be simple. Take the Ray vector, and simply add it to a vector representing the amount you want to translate by (in each axis). I don't see you doing this in your code.

So a vector (3.6, 7, 9) translated by (-4, 15, 12.2) results in a vector (-0.4, 22, 21.2).

`float?` (or any typename appended with `?`) is what's called a **nullable type**. Without that `?` you would not be able to set the variable to null. Of course, nullable types incur an overhead -- if they didn't, all types would be nullable by default.

Comment: I have this: http://t.zvb.cz/imperium/databaze/lidi/vodacek/Editor3.png and I want to know that ray from mouse intersects with boxes shown at image. Pick works fine unles when model is translated (rotating and scaling works).

Comment: Have you debugged your camera space coordinates, your mouse pick (start of ray) coordinates, and your object coordinates, at the same time? It sounds as if your conversions from screen-space to world-space (and/or vice versa) are off target.

Answer (score 1):

Your bounding box, xbouding, is somewhat inside out. Min.Y & min.Z are both greater in value than max.Y & max.Z. That's impossible for a correct bounding box & won't produce expected results because it wont allow the intersection tests to work correctly. Might or might not factor into current issue, but assuredly it will cause you problems somewhere.

try a min of (50,-10,-10) & a max of (120, 10, 10).